# Pass on the argument name and value within a function

Tags: r

I already have a few functions that manipulate both the name and other properties of the same object. While they operate fine individually, I am having trouble writing a "control" that would pass on the argument to all of them in one move.

So far, I have narrowed the problem down to the argument's name. To illustrate, the simplified code below shows the failure of passing on the name from the "control" (f2) down to the individual functions (f1).

```
x=7
f1<-function(a){
    label<-deparse(substitute(a))
    cat("f1 value:",a,"\n")
    cat("f1 label:",label,"\n")
}

f2<-function(b){
    label<-deparse(substitute(b))
    cat("f2 value:",b,"\n")
    cat("f2 label:",label,"\n")
    f1(b)
}
f2(x)


#>f2 value: 7 
#>f2 label: x 
#>f1 value: 7 
#>f1 label: b
```

It appears that the object x is properly passed on to f2, as the returned value 7 and name "x" indicates. But when calling f1 within f2, I could only pass on the value, not the name, of the object x. Correct me if I am wrong, but my understanding is that f1 only sees the binding between the name "b" and the value 7 through the argument.

Is there is a way to let f1 read both the name and value of "x" in this example? I am pretty new to R, and have tried to apply my half-baked understanding of environments, evaluation and calls to no avail. The only solution I found is to use assign "label" as global in f2 through <<-, which is far from ideal.

Thanks in advance for any input.

**Edited: the full corrected code**

Thanks to suggestions from MrFlick. Here's the code for the actual problem I was trying to solve (now fixed). Since I am new to R, I'd still appreciate suggestions on better ways to do it.

Basically I have a few dozen `lmer` (.99x version of `lme4` package) models estimated, and like the associated output to be aggregated ultimately into an Excel file. In the code below, `lmer.stats`,`lmer.fixef`, and `lmer.ranef` all create data frames based on corresponding results. `lmer.append` are used to call three these functions and `rbind` the results.

Since there are so many models, I needed an additional id variable *label* created to tell one model from another in the aggregate output. The idea is to extract the argument name and make it an identifier variable, which I had trouble with until MrFlick's kind suggestions Now the `...` fix works great.

```
## model summary statistics
lmer.stats<-function(lmer.name) {
    A<-AIC(lmer.name)
    B<-BIC(lmer.name)
    ll<-logLik(lmer.name)
    dv<-deviance(lmer.name)
    obs.TIME<-length(lmer.name@y)
    obs.CHILD<-sapply(ranef(lmer.name),nrow)[1]
    names(obs.CHILD)<-NULL
    obs.SCHOOL<-sapply(ranef(lmer.name),nrow)[2]
    names(obs.SCHOOL)<-NULL
    label<-deparse(substitute(lmer.name))
    df<-data.frame(label, "AIC"=A, "BIC"=B, "LL"=ll, "DEV"=dv, "N"=obs.TIME, "CHILD"=obs.CHILD, "SCHOOL"=obs.SCHOOL)
}
## random effects
lmer.ranef<-function(lmer.name){
    re<-data.frame(summary(lmer.name)@REmat)
    re<-subset(re,select=-Name)
    label<-deparse(substitute(lmer.name))   # identifier
    nr<-nrow(summary(lmer.name)@REmat)
    md<-data.frame(rep(label,nr))
    colnames(md)<-"Model"

    dfr<-data.frame(cbind(md,re))

    if (ncol(dfr)==4)   {       # random slope models have additional columns
        corr.col<-data.frame(rep(NA,nr))
        colnames(corr.col)<-"Corr"
        V6.col<-data.frame(rep(NA,nr))
        colnames(V6.col)<-"V6"
        dfr<-data.frame(cbind(dfr,corr.col,V6.col))
    }   else {
                dfr<-dfr
        }
}
## fixed effects
lmer.fixef<-function(lmer.name){
    beta<-data.frame("Beta"=fixef(lmer.name))
    se<-data.frame("S.E."=sqrt(diag(vcov(lmer.name))))
    vars<-data.frame(row.names(beta))
    colnames(vars)<-"Variable"
    vars$Variable<-gsub("\\)", "", vars$Variable)   # deal with (Intercept)
    vars$Variable<-gsub("\\(", "", vars$Variable)
    label<-deparse(substitute(lmer.name))   # identifier
    md<-data.frame(rep(label,length(lmer.name@fixef)))
    colnames(md)<-"Model"
    row.names(beta)<-NULL
    dff<-data.frame(cbind(md,vars,beta,se))
}
## controller
    lmer.append<-function(...,append=TRUE)  {
    label<<-deparse(substitute(...))
    if (!append){
        L.stats<<-lmer.stats(...)
        L.ranef<<-lmer.ranef(...)
        L.fixef<<-lmer.fixef(...)
    } else {
        L.stats<<-rbind(L.stats, lmer.stats(...))
        L.ranef<<-rbind(L.ranef, lmer.ranef(...))
        L.fixef<<-rbind(L.fixef, lmer.fixef(...))
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're pretty new to R and you're trying to do this, you might not be doing it "the R way." What is the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry I missed out on this comment. I was trying to automate post-estimation for `lmer` (from the the old lme4 package) and create three data frames for the fixed effects, random effects, and model summary statistics. Let me post the codes in a revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On possibility is to let the variable "fall-though" `f1` into `f2` via the "..." argument.

```
x=7
f1<-function(a){
    label<-deparse(substitute(a))
    cat("f1 value:",a,"\n")
    cat("f1 label:",label,"\n")
}

f2<-function(...) {
    label<-deparse(substitute(...))
    cat("f2 value:",eval(substitute(...)),"\n")
    cat("f2 label:",label,"\n")
    f1(...)
}
f2(x)

# f2 value: 7 
# f2 label: x 
# f1 value: 7 
# f1 label: x
```

But it really depends on why you have this arrangement at all. A more natural way might be to do this

```
x=7
f1<-function(a, label=deparse(substitute(a))) {
    cat("f1 value:",a,"\n")
    cat("f1 label:",label,"\n")
}

f2<-function(b) {
    label<-deparse(substitute(b))
    cat("f2 value:",b,"\n")
    cat("f2 label:",label,"\n")
    f1(b, label)
}
f2(x)
```

Which also returns

```
# f2 value: 7 
# f2 label: x 
# f1 value: 7 
# f1 label: x
```

and `f1(x)` still returns

```
# f1 value: 7 
# f1 label: x
```

Comment: Thanks! The ellipsis route serves my intent very well, as I only need f2 to pass on the argument to other functions in one move. I've mistaken that at least one argument needs to be specified given online examples often write "function(x,...)".

Comment: The second solution works only with the `label` line in f2, which I added for illustration purpose. Without it, I would get an "object 'label' not found" error.

Comment: @AspenChen I'm not sure I understand your last comment. The second solution assumes that you are deparsing the name of the variable in `f2` and then passing that name along to `f1` for use later. If nothing is passed to `f1` in the label parameter, it will try to deparse it automatically. The example as written should run just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I apparently made a mistake in replication. Your second solution runs just well and avoids my original proposal to make the label global. I did try to remove everything pertaining to `label` in f2. In that case, f1 goes back to returning "b" instead of "x" as the name. It seems like f2 has to either just let the argument name "fall through" (first solution) or separately pass it on (second solution).