# Show value in function passed through arguments

Tags: r, function

I have defined the next function

```
inequalizer <- function(x,caracter) {
  if(caracter=="X") {
    function(y) {y[1] < x}
  } else if(caracter=="Y") {
    function(y) {y[2] < x}
  } else {
    function(y) {y[3] < x}
  }
}
```

which returns one function depending on the input parameters `x` and `caracter`. I have another function where I call this function recursively , whose arguments depend on some initial data.

This function returned by "inequalizer" is saved as

```
function(y) {y[2] < x}
<bytecode: 'code'>
<environment: 'code'>
```

I want to know if there is some way to save it with the literal argument passed to `x`. So if those parameters are `x=1` `caracter="Y"` I would get

```
function(y) {y[2] < 1}
<bytecode: 'code'>
<environment: 'code'>
```

Comment: look up `?match.call`

Comment: Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960814/pass-on-the-argument-name-and-value-within-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe store `x` as `attr`

```
inequalizer <- function(x, caracter) {
    if(caracter=="X") {
        foo = function(y) {y[1] < x}
        attr(foo, "x") = x
        foo
    } else if(caracter=="Y") {
        foo = function(y) {y[2] < x}
        attr(foo, "x") = x
        foo
    } else {
        foo = function(y) {y[3] < x}
        attr(foo, "x") = x
        foo
    }
}

myf = inequalizer(5, "X")
myf
#function(y) {y[1] < x}
#<environment: 0x000000001c12e2d0>
#attr(,"x")
#[1] 5
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this and it made the job, but forgot to rate and comment!